# Open vim with vsp and tabs on startup

Tags: command-line, split, tabbed-user-interface

I want the following configuration:

Tab1:
file 1 || file 2

Tab2:
file 1 || file 3

I can open `vsp` with vim using

```sh
vim -O file1 file2
```

I can open tabs with vim using

```sh
vim -p file1 file2
```

Can I combine the two command line arguments somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vim file1 +'vsplit file2' +'tabedit file1' +'vsplit file3'
```

A more economic alternative is

```
vim file1 +'vs file2|tabe file1|vs file3'
```